# Building Chromium (Ubuntu) - Linker Error

Tags: google-chrome, gcc, clang, ubuntu-16.04, linker-errors

I am trying to build chromium from scratch [Checking out and building Chromium on Linux](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_build_instructions.md#System-requirements). I am using a virtual machine with 20GB RAM and 150GB HDD running a clean Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I am compiling with using the "-finstrument-functions" flag.

However when I try to build I get a wired error message (see below). To me it  looks like a linking problem. But I do not know how to fix it.

```
[21/33890] SOLINK ./libcommon.so
FAILED: libcommon.so libcommon.so.TOC 
python "../../build/toolchain/gcc_solink_wrapper.py" --readelf="readelf" --nm="nm" --sofile="./libcommon.so" --tocfile="./libcommon.so.TOC" --output="./libcommon.so"  -- ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++ -shared -Wl,--fatal-warnings -fPIC -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,defs -Wl,--no-as-needed -lpthread -Wl,--as-needed -fuse-ld=lld -Wl,--icf=all -m64 -Werror -Wl,--gdb-index -nostdlib++ --sysroot=../../build/linux/debian_jessie_amd64-sysroot -L../../build/linux/debian_jessie_amd64-sysroot/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,-rpath-link=../../build/linux/debian_jessie_amd64-sysroot/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L../../build/linux/debian_jessie_amd64-sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,-rpath-link=../../build/linux/debian_jessie_amd64-sysroot/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -o "./libcommon.so" -Wl,-soname="libcommon.so" @"./libcommon.so.rsp"
/home/chromtest/chromium/src/out/Default/../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string()
>>> referenced by gcm_messages.cc
>>>               obj/components/gcm_driver/common/common/gcm_messages.o:(gcm::OutgoingMessage::OutgoingMessage())

/home/chromtest/chromium/src/out/Default/../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__zero()
>>> referenced by gcm_messages.cc

[... more lines ...]

/home/chromtest/chromium/src/out/Default/../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/ld.lld: error: too many errors emitted, stopping now (use -error-limit=0 to see all errors)
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[22/33890] CXX obj/components/keyed_service/core/core/dependency_graph.o
[23/33890] ACTION //components/resources:about_credits(//build/toolchain/linux:clang_x64)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used these two flags (as suggested in the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/WDMvfgWuA-8)) to successfully compile Chromium

```
use_lld = false
is_component_build = false
```

Answer (score 1):

There are dedicated Chrome build instructions for clang, have you followed those?

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/clang.md

This linking error suggests that the code fails to link against the C++ runtime, which is usually `libc++` for clang (as opposed to `libstdc++` of gcc). Chrome uses clang by default, so you should have a working clang/libc++ toolchain installed.

Alternatively, you could try building with gcc instead, as explained in the above link.

Comment: I tryied to compile using `is_clang= true` and `is_clang = false`. Both did not work :(

Comment: @alive-and-well
I see. Do you have similar errors with gcc, or are they different ones? Could you post the gcc build output on pastebin?

Comment: Note that I am using the "-finstrument-functions" flag to compile the code