# Calling a shared library in C++ from Chromium results in ld.lld: error: undefined symbol:

Tags: c++, linux, chromium

Using C++, my goal is to call a function from my own shared library from within Chromium.

When I compile, I get ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: my_class::print_a_dot()

Can anyone suggest why I am getting undefined symbol? thanks!

```
ubuntu:~/chromium/src> autoninja -C out/Default chrome
ninja: Entering directory `out/Default'
[16888/17733] SOLINK ./libcontent.so
FAILED: libcontent.so libcontent.so.TOC
python3 "../../build/toolchain/gcc_solink_wrapper.py" --readelf="../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-readelf" --nm="../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-nm"  --sofile="./libcontent.so" --tocfile="./libcontent.so.TOC" --output="./libcontent.so" -- ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++ -shared -Wl,-soname="libcontent.so" -Werror -fuse-ld=lld -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--build-id -fPIC -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--color-diagnostics -Wl,--undefined-version -Wl,--no-call-graph-profile-sort -m64 -no-canonical-prefixes -Wl,--gdb-index -rdynamic -Wl,-z,defs -Wl,--as-needed -nostdlib++ --sysroot=../../build/linux/debian_bullseye_amd64-sysroot -Wl,-rpath=\$ORIGIN -o "./libcontent.so" @"./libcontent.so.rsp"
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: my_class::print_a_dot()
>>> referenced by delegated_frame_host.cc:457 (../../content/browser/renderer_host/delegated_frame_host.cc:457)
>>>               obj/content/browser/browser/delegated_frame_host.o:(content::DelegatedFrameHost::DidCopyStaleContent(std::Cr::unique_ptr<viz::CopyOutputResult, std::Cr::default_delete<viz::CopyOutputResult>>))
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[16913/17733] CXX irt_x64/obj/ipc/mojom/ipc.mojom.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

:ubuntu:~/chromium/src>

For my shared library, outside Chroimium I created a C++ source file my_class.cpp

```
ubuntu:~/learn> cat my_class.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "my_class.h"


extern void my_class::print_a_dot()
{
    std::cout << ".";
}
```

For my shared library, outside Chromium I created a C++ header file my_class.h

```
:ubuntu:~/learn> cat my_class.h
#ifndef MY_CLASS_H    // To make sure you don't declare the function more than once by including the header multiple times.
#define MY_CLASS_H

class my_class {

  public:
      static int some_number;
      static bool initialised;
      void print_a_dot();
      int init_encoder();
  };


#endif
```

For my shared library, outside Chromium I created a CMakeLists.txt

```
:ubuntu:~/learn> cat CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(MyProject)

add_library(myexample SHARED my_class.cpp)

:ubuntu:~/learn>
```

In the Chromium third_party directory named "dude4" I created a directory so Chromium can access my shared library:

```
third_party % find dude4
dude4
dude4/BUILD.gn
dude4/include
dude4/include/my_class.h
third_party %
```

The BUILD.gn contains:

```
config("my_class_import") {
  include_dirs = ["include"]
  libs = ["/home/ubuntu/learn/build/libmyexample.so"]
}

group("my_class") {
  public_configs = [":my_class_import"]
}
```

I want to call my shared library from within Chromium, so I add the following lines at the bottom of the header lines in delegated_frame_host.cc

```
#include "third_party/dude4/include/my_class.h"

//using namespace N;
bool my_class::initialised = false;
int my_class::some_number = 999;
```

And also in delegated_frame_host.cc I add some code to call my shared library:

```
void DelegatedFrameHost::DidCopyStaleContent(
    std::unique_ptr<viz::CopyOutputResult> result) {
  // host may have become visible by the time the request to capture surface is
  // completed.

    my_class mc;
    mc.initialised = false;
    std::cout << "my_class::some_number: ";
    std::cout << my_class::some_number << std::endl;
    my_class::some_number = 888;
    std::cout << "mc.some_number: ";
    std::cout << mc.some_number << std::endl;
    my_class nc;
    std::cout << "nc.some_number: ";
    std::cout << nc.some_number << std::endl;

    if (mc.initialised == false) {
        std::cout << "initialising encoder" << std::endl;
        mc.initialised = true;
    }
    mc.print_a_dot();
(code of this function continues.......)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47387431/627492

Summary:

gn args out/Default

```
use_lld = false
is_component_build = false
```